# finding common integers in 2 unsorted Arrays using recursion

Tags: arrays, recursion

you are given 2 arrays of integers (unsorted) and you need to print the common between them, The example I used is, int[] list1 = {4,5,6,7,8} //// int[] list2 = {2,3,4,8,10,16}

the output I have got is: 4 BUT the CORRECT output is 4 8

here is my code :

```
public static void commonElements(int[] a,int[] b){
helper(a,b,0,0);
    }
    public static void helper(int[] a, int[] b,int i,int j){
        if(i == a.length || j ==b.length){
            return;
        }else if(a[i] == b[j]) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
            helper(a,b,++i,0);
        } else {
            helper(a, b, i, j+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If j advances to the end, then you hit the "done" condition, and ... you're done, even though you've not done with i. It doesn't continue with other i values. Also, recursion here is used as an equivalent to iteration, which is not a good way to solve this problem. Are you interested in this problem, or just practicing recursion?

Comment: What would you expect as output for `{1,1,1}` and `{1,1,1,1,1}`?

Comment: I'm practicing recursion, so I need to use it somehow,

Comment: for {1,1,1} it returns 1 1 1 so it doesn't work probably

Answer (score 0):

Once `j` has reached the end, your code does not increment `i`. In that case you execute `return`, and as all your recursive calls are tail calls, there is nothing more that happens during the unwinding of the recursion chain.

The quick fix -- keeping the same coding pattern -- is to replace this:

```java
        if(i == a.length || j ==b.length){
            return;
        }
```

with this:

```java
        if (i == a.length) {
            return;
        } else if (j == b.length) {
            helper(a, b, ++i, 0);
        }
```

#### Heavy on the stack

This recursive approach has a worst case space complexity of O(²). This is not very memory efficient. JVM does currently not optimise tail calls which would solve *that* problem.

Besides that, the time complexity is not optimal either. You can solve this by creating a HashSet of the values that are in the second array, and then call `contains` instead of looping through the second array.

```java
    public static void commonElements(int[] a, int[] b){
        Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(b).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        for (int val : a) {
            if (set.contains(val)) {
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        }
    }
```